# Azure AD OIDC changing preferred_username format

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I've set up a Registered App for OIDC and configured it for various usages on Azure AD.

The application I integrate with uses `preferred_username` in the ID Token for various things. Azure AD assigns `username@company.com`, a.k.a. UPN to this field. I'd like it to assign `username` which could be the good old SamAccountName or UPN transformed in some way.
Is there any way to do this?

This seems to be possible for SAML (`NameId` is kind of equivalent to `preferred_hostname` on OIDC the way I see it) but I couldn't find anything relevant for OIDC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization#editing-nameid

I've tried changing manifest file in the app with some educated guess but did not managed to accomplish this. I could not find anything related in [manifest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps).

Answer (score 1):

The ID token is the core extension that [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) makes to OAuth 2.0. ID tokens are issued by the authorization server and contain claims that carry information about the user.

OpenID Connect (OIDC) is an authentication protocol built on OAuth 2.0 that you can use to securely sign in a user to an application

These are list of `claim` for ID token you can configure before generating a `token`

**AzureAD-ADApplication->Token Configuration-> Add an optional claim.**

There you can able see list of claim including UPN as well.

[image]

Claim for samaAccount only under group claim.

[image]

Comment: I have checked these settings and they do not modify the existing `preferred_username` claim (also an OIDC standard). Adding a `upn` optional claim, would only add a new field to the ID token, and samAccountName in "Edit groups claim" only affects the `groups` claim. My focus is `preferred_username`.